# configuration of cancan and devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, cancan

I use this tutorial:

http://www.roberthuberdeau.com/articles/9-Blog-tutorial-part-3

I didn't understand how to do these step:

> We only created a role model. We're left with two choices- finish the scaffold for the role class or create the roles using the command console. I went with the latter as I have command line access to my production environment. I created the following roles, Admin, Moderator, and Author in this exact order. This will be important latter when we set a default user role.

I want to do the second option:

I don't know how I have to create the roles using the command console. I want to create the following roles: Admin and Worker in this exact order.

can someone write me the commands please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the shell run `bundle exec rails console`. This opens up an IRB terminal with your Rails environment loaded, and you will have access to methods such as: `Role.create({name: "Admin"})`

Comment: thank you but I got an error: Can't mass-assign protected attributes: name, so I have to add to the role model: attr_accessible :name, right?

Comment: Yes, or assign name on its own: `role = Role.new; role.name = "Admin"; role.save`